# How to delete Windows 7 virtual drive

Tags: windows-7, subst

I created a virtual drive using "SUBST" command. But I can not delete now.

Can anybody tell me how can I delete this virtual drive.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If using the command  `SUBST X: /D` does not work then try `rem` or delete the occurrence of the SUBST command in the autoexec.bat file & reboot.

If using Windows 7, try to open your prompt window as Administrator and then run the `SUBST X: /D` normally

Comment: Windows 7 does not read `autoexec.bat`.

Comment: It does read it under some circumstances

Answer (score 13):

After doing a Google search (taking less than a minute) I found [this](http://discussions.virtualdr.com/showthread.php?8390-Deleting-A-SUBST-Hard-Drive):

```
SUBST X: /D
```

where X is the SUBST drive

Comment: let me quote [this SO comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions#comment141206_8724): Imagine you google for a question, and the first search result that comes up is a StackOverflow post for exactly the question you need. So you click on it, read the answer... and what does it say? “Just google for it!”