# Remove virtual drive win10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virtualization

After building a PC using drives ffrom my previous system I had to ditch my E: drive due to limited SATA power subbly.
Programs on and reference to E: were obviously broken. To an extend where I resorted to the `subst` command to be able to reinstall stoftware taht had previously been installed in E. 
Now, how do I get sid of the dublication of my C drive?

I found this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/541120/how-to-delete-windows-7-virtual-drive) on the same topic but for Win7. It did not work stating that E: is an invalid argument.

What do I do now?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: First of all, are you SURE there is still an E:?? If you are, did you try rebooting?  subst doesn't persist between boots.

Comment: As a computing science student, I feel emberassed not to think of the good old "turn it off and on again" myself. Did the trick...

Comment: Should I answer my question myself or is it trivial enough to be worth deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUBST command doesn't persist between boots, so remove the E: virtual drive by turning the computer off and turning it on again.